# EF Core RC2 migrations failing during publish/deployment

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, webdeploy, entity-framework-migrations

When running a publish for a small test ASP.NET Core MVC project I am having some difficulties automatically running migrations against the live database.

If I publish with both **Settings / Databases / Default Connection / Use this connection string at runtime** and **Settings / Databases / Entity Framework Migrations / ApplicationDbContext** unchecked then the site publishes fine, but the database is, as expected, left untouched.

If I publish with **Settings / Databases / Default Connection / Use this connection string at runtime** checked then it seems to copy my entire development database to the live server, including all of the data. Definitely not what I need.

If I publish with **Settings / Databases / Entity Framework Migrations / ApplicationDbContext** checked then I receive the following error:

```
Configuring the following project for use with IIS: 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\PublishTemp\TestProject57'
Updating web.config at 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\PublishTemp\TestProject57\web.config'
Configuring project completed successfully
publish: Published to C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\PublishTemp\TestProject57
Published 1/1 projects successfully
Publishing with publish method [MSDeploy]
Executing command ["C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe" -source:manifest='C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\PublishTemp\obj\SourceManifest.xml' -dest:manifest='C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\PublishTemp\obj\DestManifest.xml',ComputerName='https://xxx:8172/msdeploy.axd',UserName='xxx',Password='{PASSWORD-REMOVED-FROM-LOG}',IncludeAcls='False',AuthType='Basic' -verb:sync -enablerule:AppOffline -retryAttempts:20 -allowUntrusted]
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DotNet\Microsoft.DotNet.Publishing.targets(406,5): Error : Error: (08/06/2016 08:29:36) An error occurred when the request was processed on the remote computer.
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DotNet\Microsoft.DotNet.Publishing.targets(406,5): Error : Error: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\PublishTemp\obj\TestProject.Models.Database.ApplicationDbContext.sql'.
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DotNet\Microsoft.DotNet.Publishing.targets(406,5): Error :    at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.NativeMethods.RaiseIOExceptionFromErrorCode(Win32ErrorCode errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DotNet\Microsoft.DotNet.Publishing.targets(406,5): Error :    at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.FileStreamEx.CreateInstance(String path, FileMode fileMode, FileAccess fileAccess, FileShare fileShare, Nullable`1 fileLength)
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DotNet\Microsoft.DotNet.Publishing.targets(406,5): Error :    at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.ReadWriteScriptFileProvider.GetFileStream()
Info: Using ID 'xxx' for connections to the remote server.
Info: Adding child sitemanifest (C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\PublishTemp\obj\TestProject.Models.Database.ApplicationDbContext.sql).
Info: Using ID 'xxx' for connections to the remote server.
Info: Updating file (TestProject\web.config).
Info: Updating file (TestProject\wwwroot\css\site.min.css).
Info: Adding child sitemanifest (C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\PublishTemp\obj\TestProject.Models.Database.ApplicationDbContext.sql).
Info: Adding database (sitemanifest/dbFullSql[@path='C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\PublishTemp\obj\TestProject.Models.Database.ApplicationDbContext.sql']/sqlScript)

C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DotNet\Microsoft.DotNet.Publishing.targets(406,5): Error :    at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.ReadWriteScriptFileProvider.Add(DeploymentObject source, Boolean whatIf)
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DotNet\Microsoft.DotNet.Publishing.targets(406,5): Error :    at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentObject.AddChild(DeploymentObject source, Int32 position, DeploymentSyncContext syncContext)
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DotNet\Microsoft.DotNet.Publishing.targets(406,5): Error :    at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.HandleAddChild(DeploymentObject destParent, DeploymentObject sourceObject, Int32 position)
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DotNet\Microsoft.DotNet.Publishing.targets(406,5): Error :    at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.SyncChildrenOrder(DeploymentObject dest, DeploymentObject source)
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DotNet\Microsoft.DotNet.Publishing.targets(406,5): Error :    at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.HandleAddChild(DeploymentObject destParent, DeploymentObject sourceObject, Int32 position)
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DotNet\Microsoft.DotNet.Publishing.targets(406,5): Error :    at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.SyncChildrenOrder(DeploymentObject dest, DeploymentObject source)
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DotNet\Microsoft.DotNet.Publishing.targets(406,5): Error :    at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.ProcessSync(DeploymentObject destinationObject, DeploymentObject sourceObject)
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DotNet\Microsoft.DotNet.Publishing.targets(406,5): Error :    at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentObject.SyncToInternal(DeploymentObject destObject, DeploymentSyncOptions syncOptions, PayloadTable payloadTable, ContentRootTable contentRootTable, Nullable`1 syncPassId, String syncSessionId)
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DotNet\Microsoft.DotNet.Publishing.targets(406,5): Error :    at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentAgent.HandleSync(DeploymentAgentAsyncData asyncData, Nullable`1 passId, String user, String siteName)
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DotNet\Microsoft.DotNet.Publishing.targets(406,5): Error : Error count: 1.

1>Publish failed due to build errors. Check the error list for more details.
```

Everything works perfectly if I click **Preview Migration** under **Entity Framework Migrations** on the **Preview** tab of the publish dialog, copy the generated SQL migration and then run it manually against the server. Also, once the migrations have been correctly applied, the application itself runs flawlessly - the point of failure is specifically when the publish process attempts to apply the migrations.

My connection strings are also identical, as both development and live have a database with identical names and use integrated security, which as the site works after I manually run the migrations, must be configured correctly.

What I'd really like to do is get to the bottom of the error when running with **Settings / Databases / Entity Framework Migrations / ApplicationDbContext** checked, as I'm pretty sure that's the option I want. The error sounds like it's trying to run a SQL file on the server with a path local to my development machine, but I'm stumped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was an issue in the preview1 tooling for Publishing with EF Migrations. This has been fixed - https://github.com/aspnet/vsweb-publish/commit/b46d54f74d7298e65dde1622bda340af3b23713f

To fix this issue:
1. Either update the tooling to Preview2 version. if you already have the publishprofile and ps1 file, delete the ps1 file and publish. This will bring down the newer version of ps1. https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=817245
2. Copy the contents of this file
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aspnet/vsweb-publish/master/publish-module.psm1 to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\Publish\Scripts\1.1.0\publish-module.psm1 
(it would be 1.1.0 or 1.2.0 based on the tooling installed.).

This should fix the issue. 
Detailed walk through of publishing an ASP.NET core app to App Service with EF migration
https://dotnetpublish.wordpress.com/2016/07/05/publish-an-asp-net-core-web-app-with-ef-migrations-to-azure-appservice/